# How to create a stored procedure to copy data from a query to a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, temp-tables

I have need of inserting data to a temporary table from an existing table/query.  The following produces the error detailed below.

```
CREATE TABLE SPTemporary
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * into #temppT
        FROM SampleTable
END
```

Throws this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin'.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This code makes no sense.  You are using `into` already in the subquery.  That doesn't return any results.

Comment: sql server 2014 @jarlh

Comment: Isn't this just a typographical error? `CREATE TABLE` should be `CREATE PROC` or `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: yes my bad @Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your syntax, use `procedure` instead of `table` :

```
create procedure SPTemporay
as
begin
select * into #temppT
from SampleTable
end
```

However, if you want only copy of data then only subquery is enough :

```
select st.* into #temppT
from SampleTable st
```

Comment: create procedure SPTemporay
as
begin
select*into #temppT
from PracticeTable
end;   when i do this it worked but, again is i do - select*from #temppT; this error is been thrown Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Invalid object name '#temppT'.

Comment: @VenkatRamana. . . When SP Return your temporary table will discarded. Temporary table scope will be limited to current session only. So, easy solution is use `select * into #temppT from SampleTable` & use that temporary table in the current session.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select st.*
into SPTemporay
from SampleTable st
```

One `select` can only put data in one table.  It is unclear which one you really want `SPTemporary` or `#temppT`.  You can repeat the `select` if you really need the same data in two tables.

EDIT:

If you want a *stored* procedure, you could do:

```
create procedure SPTemporay
as begin
    select *
    into #temppT
    from SampleTable
end;
```

This is rather non-sensical, because the temporary table is discarded when the stored procedure returns.

Comment: here i want to copy data from sample table to #temporary table

Answer (score -2):

I think the syntax is wrong, it should be like that:

```
create table SPTemporay
as
select * from SampleTable
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Por favor, Stackoverflow está en idioma inglés.